# The container does not start after starting the database

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I want to run my server in `docker`, which I wrote on `nest.js`, the databases I use `mysql` and `ormtype`. Here is my `dockerfile` and `docker-compose.yml`.

```
#dockerfile
FROM node:12.13.0-alpine

WORKDIR /src

COPY ./package.json .
COPY ./package-lock.json .

RUN npm install

COPY . .

EXPOSE 8081

CMD npm run start:dev
```

```
# docker-compose.yml
version: "3.3"

services:
  mysql:
    container_name: mysql
    image: mysql:5.7.27
    ports:
      - 3306:3306
    expose:
      - 3306
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
      MYSQL_USER: root
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: root
      MYSQL_DATABASE: root
    restart: always

  server:
    container_name: sever
    command: ["./wait-for-it.sh", "mysql:3306", "--", "npm", "run", "start:dev"]
    depends_on:
      - mysql
    links:
      - mysql
    build:
      context: server
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    environment:
      PORT: 8081
    ports:
      - 8081:8081
    restart: on-failure
    volumes:
      - ./server:/src/
```

I made the server wait for the database to start. But after the server starts, I get an error.

```
user1@ps:~/documents/projects/project1$ sudo docker-compose up --build
Creating network "project1_default" with the default driver
Building server
Step 1/8 : FROM node:12.13.0-alpine
 ---> 5d187500daae
Step 2/8 : WORKDIR /src
 ---> Using cache
 ---> b6f4bc8d73d2
Step 3/8 : COPY ./package.json .
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 83ece116c790
Step 4/8 : COPY ./package-lock.json .
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 24c334b23d56
Step 5/8 : RUN npm install
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 1cf26bbbf0b0
Step 6/8 : COPY . .
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 7760703813f9
Step 7/8 : EXPOSE 8081
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 8edce63e71c9
Step 8/8 : CMD npm run start:dev
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 5c726b1b930b

Successfully built 5c726b1b930b
Successfully tagged project1_server:latest
Creating mysql ... done
Creating sever ... done
Attaching to mysql, sever
mysql     | Initializing database
sever     | env: can't execute 'bash': No such file or directory
mysql     | 2019-11-14T10:20:22.270941Z 0 [Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is deprecated. Please use --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp server option (see documentation for more details).
mysql     | 2019-11-14T10:20:22.912746Z 0 [Warning] InnoDB: New log files created, LSN=45790
mysql     | 2019-11-14T10:20:23.040600Z 0 [Warning] InnoDB: Creating foreign key constraint system tables.
mysql     | 2019-11-14T10:20:23.117486Z 0 [Warning] No existing UUID has been found, so we assume that this is the first time that this server has been started. Generating a new UUID: 5e28b9cc-06c8-11ea-bd8a-0242ac120002.
mysql     | 2019-11-14T10:20:23.123840Z 0 [Warning] Gtid table is not ready to be used. Table 'mysql.gtid_executed' cannot be opened.
mysql     | 2019-11-14T10:20:23.124967Z 1 [Warning] root@localhost is created with an empty password ! Please consider switching off the --initialize-insecure option.
sever exited with code 0
sever exited with code 127
mysql     | Database initialized
mysql     | Initializing certificates
mysql     | Generating a RSA private key
mysql     | ................+++++
mysql     | ...............................................+++++
mysql     | unable to write 'random state'
mysql     | writing new private key to 'ca-key.pem'
mysql     | -----
mysql     | Generating a RSA private key
mysql     | ....+++++
mysql     | ................................................+++++
mysql     | unable to write 'random state'
mysql     | writing new private key to 'server-key.pem'
mysql     | -----
mysql     | Generating a RSA private key
mysql     | .......................................................................................................................+++++
mysql     | .............+++++
mysql     | unable to write 'random state'
mysql     | writing new private key to 'client-key.pem'
mysql     | -----
mysql     | Certificates initialized
mysql     | MySQL init process in progress...
sever exited with code 127
mysql     | 2019-11-14T10:20:29.192610Z 0 [Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is deprecated. Please use --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp server option (see documentation for more details).
mysql     | 2019-11-14T10:20:29.193767Z 0 [Note] mysqld (mysqld 5.7.27) starting as process 91 ...
mysql     | 2019-11-14T10:20:29.196140Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: PUNCH HOLE support available
mysql     | 2019-11-14T10:20:29.196154Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
mysql     | 2019-11-14T10:20:29.196157Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
mysql     | 2019-11-14T10:20:29.196159Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: GCC builtin __atomic_thread_fence() is used for memory barrier
mysql     | 2019-11-14T10:20:29.196162Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
mysql     | 2019-11-14T10:20:29.196164Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
mysql     | 2019-11-14T10:20:29.196387Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
mysql     | 2019-11-14T10:20:29.196491Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using CPU crc32 instructions
mysql     | 2019-11-14T10:20:29.197706Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 128M, instances = 1, chunk size = 128M
mysql     | 2019-11-14T10:20:29.203604Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
mysql     | 2019-11-14T10:20:29.205704Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: If the mysqld execution user is authorized, page cleaner thread priority can be changed. See the man page of setpriority().
mysql     | 2019-11-14T10:20:29.216931Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
mysql     | 2019-11-14T10:20:29.232083Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
mysql     | 2019-11-14T10:20:29.232827Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file './ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
mysql     | 2019-11-14T10:20:29.389401Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: File './ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
mysql     | 2019-11-14T10:20:29.391548Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: 96 redo rollback segment(s) found. 96 redo rollback segment(s) are active.
mysql     | 2019-11-14T10:20:29.391575Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: 32 non-redo rollback segment(s) are active.
mysql     | 2019-11-14T10:20:29.392343Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
mysql     | 2019-11-14T10:20:29.442516Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: 5.7.27 started; log sequence number 2625438
mysql     | 2019-11-14T10:20:29.442792Z 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
mysql     | 2019-11-14T10:20:29.446146Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from /var/lib/mysql/ib_buffer_pool
mysql     | 2019-11-14T10:20:29.447290Z 0 [Note] Found ca.pem, server-cert.pem and server-key.pem in data directory. Trying to enable SSL support using them.
mysql     | 2019-11-14T10:20:29.447479Z 0 [Warning] CA certificate ca.pem is self signed.
mysql     | 2019-11-14T10:20:29.447503Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) load completed at 191114 10:20:29
mysql     | 2019-11-14T10:20:29.466159Z 0 [Warning] Insecure configuration for --pid-file: Location '/var/run/mysqld' in the path is accessible to all OS users. Consider choosing a different directory.
mysql     | 2019-11-14T10:20:29.473779Z 0 [Note] Event Scheduler: Loaded 0 events
mysql     | 2019-11-14T10:20:29.474160Z 0 [Note] mysqld: ready for connections.
mysql     | Version: '5.7.27'  socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'  port: 0  MySQL Community Server (GPL)
sever exited with code 127
mysql     | Warning: Unable to load '/usr/share/zoneinfo/iso3166.tab' as time zone. Skipping it.
mysql     | Warning: Unable to load '/usr/share/zoneinfo/leap-seconds.list' as time zone. Skipping it.
mysql     | Warning: Unable to load '/usr/share/zoneinfo/zone.tab' as time zone. Skipping it.
mysql     | Warning: Unable to load '/usr/share/zoneinfo/zone1970.tab' as time zone. Skipping it.
mysql     | mysql: [Warning] Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
mysql     | mysql: [Warning] Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
mysql     | ERROR 1396 (HY000) at line 1: Operation CREATE USER failed for 'root'@'%'
sever exited with code 127
sever     | env: can't execute 'bash': No such file or directory
sever     | env: can't execute 'bash': No such file or directory
sever     | env: can't execute 'bash': No such file or directory
sever     | env: can't execute 'bash': No such file or directory
sever     | env: can't execute 'bash': No such file or directory
sever     | env: can't execute 'bash': No such file or directory
```

Where did I make a mistake? How can I properly start my server in a docker container.

Comment: Maybe there is something wrong with the `wait-for-it.sh`. Can you post it as well?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your base image `node:12.13.0-alpine` is base on alpine, where `wait-for-it` is the base on bash, there `ash` in alpine `no` bash.

The error logs seem very clear.

```
can't execute 'bash': No such file or directory
```

One option that you can try is to add bash in your nodejs Dockerfile

```
FROM node:12.13.0-alpine

WORKDIR /src
RUN apk add --no-cache bash
```

and then try to run.

But here is the created issue for alpine

[Can you make an /bin/sh version for use with alpine linux ? #18](https://github.com/vishnubob/wait-for-it/issues/18)

Or you can use [docker-wait-for-it-alpine](https://github.com/billylaing/docker-wait-for-it-alpine)

Comment: I did not know this, how can I fix it?